# How to change values in a data frame at different indexes

Tags: python, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe of size 100 and i have an array of 20 values stored in x

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.arange(100)})
```

How can I change values at index 70 to 90 with the array x

Answer (score 1):

Just index the dataframe on that position, `at` is enough for single value indexing:

```
df.at[70, 'value'] = 90
```

For indices 70 to 90:

```
df.loc[70:90, 'value'] = 90
```

Comment: I want to replace all values from index 70 to 90 with the values stored in another variable e g (array x)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[70:90,0] = x
```

Here `70:90` is the row number (starts at 0), and the `0` is the column index

You can also use .loc if your index is numerated (like yours):

70-90 is actually 21 numbers, so i will assume for this example that you actually want to change where the indices go from 70-89 inclusive.

```
df.loc[70:89,"value"] = x
```